# Obtain the CDF of a Vine Copula (trivariate) in R

Tags: r, large-data, cdf, multivariate-testing

I'm aware that the "VineCopula" package has a RVinePDF function and a BiCopCDF function, however there is no RVineCDF function. I need to select and fit R-Vine Copulas to a subset of three variables with 40 observations in a dataset with 300+ levels of a grouping variable (think of fitting a copula to each municipality in Texas based on precipitation, temperature and solar radiation data).

Is there any alternative using the RVineStructureSelect and RVineCopSelect pipeline?

Answer (score 0):

There are many other vine copula packages, but not sure if they will be good for your question, for example, `vinereg` (for fitting regression D-vine copula), `vinecopulib` (similar to the `VineCopula` but take into account the marginals).